# Custom function does not work in R 'ddply' function

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to use a custom function inside 'ddply' in order to create a new variable (NormViability) in my data frame, based on values of a pre-existing variable (CelltiterGLO).
The function is meant to create a rescaled (%) value of 'CelltiterGLO' based on the mean 'CelltiterGLO' values at a specific sub-level of the variable 'Concentration_nM' (0.01).
So if the mean of 'CelltiterGLO' at 'Concentration_nM'==0.01 is set as 100, I want to rescale all other values of 'CelltiterGLO' over the levels of other variables ('CTSC', 'Time_h' and 'ExpType').

The normalization function is the following:

```
  normalize.fun = function(CelltiterGLO) {

         idx = Concentration_nM==0.01
         jnk = mean(CelltiterGLO[idx], na.rm = T)
         out = 100*(CelltiterGLO/jnk)
         return(out) 

  }
```

and this is the code I try to apply to my dataframe:

```
library("plyr")

df.bis=ddply(df,
             .(CTSC, Time_h, ExpType),
             transform, 
             NormViability = normalize.fun(CelltiterGLO))
```

The code runs, but when I try to double check (aggregate or tapply) if the mean of 'NormViability' equals '100' at 'Concentration_nM'==0.01, I do not get 100, but different numbers. The fact is that, if I try to subset my df by the two levels of the variable 'ExpType', the code returns the correct numbers on each separated subset. I tried to make 'ExpType' either character or factor but I got similar results. 'ExpType has two levels/values which are "Combinations" and "DoseResponse", respectively. I can't figure out why the code is not working on the entire df, I wonder if this is due to the fact that the two levels of 'ExpType' do not contain the same number of levels for all the other variables, e.g. one of the levels of 'Time_h' is missing for the level "Combinations" of 'ExpType'.

Thanks very much for your help and I apologize in advance if the answer is already present in Stackoverflow and I was not able to find it.

Michele

Comment: I think you just need to delete "NormViability=" .  Check the examples under `?ddply`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried deleting "NormViability=" but then I get no new variable in the new dataframe. I tried to rename the new variable to a shorter name with no capitals but didn't work. This same code worked in a similar dataset with fewer grouping variables.

Answer (score -1):

I (the OP) found out that the function was missing one variable in the arguments, that was used in the statements. Simply adding the variable `Concentration_nM` to the custom function solved the problem.
THANKS
m.

Comment: If you really are the OP, you should have logged in as @user3013002 and post an answer to your own question, possibly accepting this answer. You could also still have changed your user name to "Michele", if you wanted to do this.